# text not hidden within table

Tags: html, html-table, hidden

I am quite confused by the following `html` markup

```html
<table id="tableCharts" hidden=true>
  <tr>
    <table id="tableResetLinks">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="test"><b>Reset All</b></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="chart-pie-pnlperstrategy">
      <div class="chart-title">PnL by Strategy</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would expect the `hidden=true` style element to apply to the whole `tableCharts` table but it doesn't as the text `PnL by Strategy`shows up no matter what the `hidden` parameter is set to.

`hidden=true` does work for the `tableResetLinks` table though.

The code above is a simplification of my actual code. I do need the child table in there.

Must be something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the child table, what can you do is use a wrapper *(like a `<div>`)* to wrap the whole table, and put the `hidden` there

```html
<div hidden>
<table id="tableCharts">
  <tr>
    <table id="tableResetLinks">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="test"><b>Reset All</b></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="chart-pie-pnlperstrategy">
      <div class="chart-title">PnL by Strategy</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have simplified my code for the purpose of the question though. I do need the child table in there.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I validated the answer since it works but i'm still not sure what the issue is with nested tables.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
<table id="tableCharts" style="visibility:hidden">
```

or

```
<table id="tableCharts" style="display:none">
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/five-ways-to-hide-elements-in-css/